# Função do excel reconhece "" como 0

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou fazendo uma função bem simples no Excel, mas estou com problemas, pois ele está reconhecendo "" como 0, segue a função:

```
=SE(E4=0;"0x0";"")
```

O problema é que está retornando "0x0" quando deixo a célula em branco, sendo que era pra retornar "0x0" somente quando tivesse o valor 0 na célula. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Forma mais fácil

Você pode fazer desta forma

```
=SE(E(E4=0;E4<>"");"0x0";"")
```

Coloquei um "E", assim ele verifica também se é diferente de "" (String vazia)

## Utilizando uma função do Excel

Existe uma função do Excel `ÉCÉL.VAZIA`, que verifica se a celula esta vazia, porém prefiro o método anterior, pois fica menor e mais fácil para ler.

```
=SE(E(E4=0;NÃO(ÉCÉL.VAZIA(E4)));"0x0";"")
```

## Resposta mais elegante

[Ranier Cordeiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364202/74441)

Comment: Muito obrigado, esta solução funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Por favor, avalie e a maque como resposta :)

Comment: Marquei como resposta, mas avaliar não consigo, pois tenho reputação baixa.

Comment: Muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Além da resposta do [Wictor Chaves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74441/wictor-chaves), pode-se fazer, também, da seguinte maneira:

```
=SE(E4&1="01";"0x0";"")
```

Assim, mesmo se passar por uma célula vazia(*""*), irá retornar o valor *falso* da condição *se*

Comment: Show, não sabia que podia usar "&" no Excel, acho que foi a resposta mais elegante +1